# Is pen pressure supposed to be dependent on the strength setting and is there a way to unhook them?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

Drew 1 line with the mouse, the next with the pen trying to go from softest to hardest. If the strength is set on .1, I can't draw hard enough to get to .5.

In photoshop ect I can get the full pressure range, but not in Blender. My first pen (a Huion) and not sure if this is proper functionality in Blender or if there is a way to turn it off.

Comment: For others coming across this. The default tip didn't work right for whatever reason in blender. Makes no sense why it worked better in PS. Changed the tip out and it's been working as expected for months now in blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two toggles will allow you to enable and disable pen pressure

[image]

> In photoshop ect I can get the full pressure range

If you want to have the full pressure range, always keep your *strength* at `1.000`. the *strength* slider sets the upper limit of strength that your pen can output.

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't find anywhere that the strength slider sets the upper limit. Guess the pen I got doesn't work well with blender because mine isn't working like that.